# Iterate last values present in a JSON response using java

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to iterate and get the last  values like name, url and color from below JSON response. Using java/gson api. Please help me on this.

```
    {
  "Title": {
    "desc": [
      {
        "name": "PRE_DB",
        "url": "http://jenkins.example.com/job/my_first_job/",
        "color": "blue_anime"
      },
      {
        "name": "SDD_Seller_Dashboard",
        "url": "http://jenkins.example.com/job/my_second_job/",
        "color": "blue_anime"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

example output : 
name : SDD_Seller_Dashboard
color :blue_anime

Comment: How do you expect Gson to deal with XML that you call a JSON response?

Comment: What did you try so far to get those json properties? Update your tried code.

Comment: i used below code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(your_JSON_Repsonse);
JSONArray data_desc=data.getJSONArray(desc);
for(int i=0;i<=data_desc.length();i++)
{
 name=data_desc.getString("name");
url=data_desc.getString("url");
color=data_desc.getString("color");
}
```

Comment: Dear Anil - 1-in you code the second line wud be                                            JSONArray data_desc=data.getJSONArray("desc");as a hardcoded string ? or ("Title"). 2- How code know where to start iteration; as the response start from Title, not from desc?.. pls suggest

Comment: JSONObject data = new JSONObject(your_rsponse_object);     JSONObject  dat_Ob=data.getObject(title'); JSONArray data_desc=dat_Ob.getJSONArray(desc);  tittle is a object, the array "desc" is inside the Object. In order to iterate the Array elements first you need to extract Objec